# How to add multiple subscriptions with firebase stripe extension?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate subscriptions plans to my project that would be similar to Patreon.

My Goal is to have an array that is synced with stripe that looks like this:

`activePlans: [planId1,planId2,planId3]`, so I can validate it on the frontend.

I came across Firebase Stripe extension and while testing it I found that I can only add one subscription to firebase auth custom claims.

Under claims there is `stripeRole` field and I can only set it with one string of the subscription product. If user subscribes to another it gets overwritten, instead of being an array.

Since stripe extension syncs users with firestore database, but once again it lacks the `activePlans` array with the plans that the user subscribed to, instead it has subcollection of subscription documents that include active and expired memberships.

Is there a way to modify this extension to achieve my goal or is it only capable of handling single subscription plan?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same checkout session is not supported, the only way could be to create one subscription with multiple prices.

One option could be to create multiple subscriptions; your system will need to send the user through checkout N times for N subscriptions.

Another possibility could be not to use checkout and to collect a customer’s payment details using elements.
Here is a documentation that could help you: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

This guide walks you through how to create fixed-price subscriptions for a photo hosting service. It shows you how to use Stripe Elements to create a custom payment form you embed in your application.

Github example using Elements: https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/v1.0/fixed-price-subscriptions

Elements validates user input as it is typed. To help your customers catch mistakes, listen to change events on the card Element and display any errors.